# stop Eclipse inserting newlines before comments

Tags: php, eclipse, comments, aptana

This post relates to use of the Aptana plugin, and PHP, but I've found the same annoying behaviour with Java and Python.

When you have some lines like this:

```
// Database handling
var $hostname;  // note: xxx
var $user_name;     // note: yyy
var $pwd;   // note: zzz
```

and you do autoformat on the file it always ends up like this:

```
// Database handling
var $hostname;
// note: xxx
var $user_name;
// note: yyy
var $pwd;
// note: zzz
```

... under Window -> Prefs -> Aptana -> Formatter -> (my created Profile) -> PHP -> Edit icon -> Comments tab there is no way to stop this annoying newline insertion happening.

Anyone know of a solution/workaround?

Comment: call you variables $hostname, $username and $password, so you don’t need explanations for that.

Comment: rename them i.e. $pwd to $password

Comment: Well, you wanted a solution or a workaround, so i proposed a workaround, that also improved your code quality.

Answer (score 0):

anyone interested, semicolons seem to be the culprits here, meaning that this (not ideal) will work for the mean time:

```
var $ext/* STUFF2 */;
```

incidentally, I also tried

```
// @formatter:off
...
// @formatter:on:
```

this did **not** stop the automatic newlines before comments in the "off" section.  Weird.

Comment: I tried all possible settings in auto-formater, in line wrapping tab, in comments tab, in new line tab, whatever made remote sense. I also tried using /* */ for every line as you proposed. It still pushes the entire comment down the line. Problem still not solved.